# Typescript iterate object with enum keys

Tags: typescript

I would like to iterate over an object with enum keys. Problem is that the types are always interfering and I would prefer to not cast everything.

```js
enum MyEnum { A, B, C }
type MyMap = { [key in MyEnum]: string };
const myMap: MyMap = {
    [MyEnum.A]: 'a?',
    [MyEnum.B]: 'b',
    [MyEnum.C]: 'c...',
};
```

If I try `Object.keys` or `for..in` it always shows errors.

```js
Object.keys(myMap).forEach(key => {
    const data = myMap[key]; // <= Error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'MyMap' has no index signature.
});
// same with: for (const key in myMap) {

Object.keys(myMap).forEach((key: MyEnum) => { // Error TS2345: Argument of ... Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'MyEnum'.
});
```

I could cast the key but can't even do it directly...

```js
Object.keys(myMap).forEach(key => {
    const data = myMap[key as MyEnum]; // Error TS2352: Conversion of type 'string' to type 'MyEnum' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.

    // have to do this but would prefer not to
    const data2 = myMap[key as unknown as MyEnum];
});
```

There probably is a solution somewhere but I didn't use the right keywords and didn't find it :( (edit: or maybe not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I'm most happy with now is adding a helper function that does the casting of the keys. This is also easily reusable for all kinds of similar objects.

```
export function objectKeys<Obj extends object>(obj: Obj): (keyof Obj)[] {
    return Object.keys(obj) as (keyof Obj)[];
}

// with example from above
// no specific type for the map needed
const myMap = {
    [MyEnum.A]: 'a?',
    [MyEnum.B]: 'b',
    [MyEnum.C]: 'c...',
};
objectKeys(myMap).forEach(key => {
  // key: MyEnum
  // if the enum has more values that are not part of the map (D..)
  // the types are still correct => key: MyEnum.A | MyEnum.B | MyEnum.C
});
```

Note: It's not perfect.
e.g. with arrays

```
objectKeys([]).forEach(key => {
  // key: number | 'length' | ...
  // would be perfect if it returned only `number` or even `never` (empty array)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use `any` or `unknown`

```
    const data = myMap[MyEnum[key as keyof typeof MyEnum]];
```